# Ctrl w +/- not working as expected

Tags: key-bindings, split

I'm trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> to change my split width and height, but it's changing the font size instead. Any ideas about what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably pressing `Ctrl-W`, `Ctrl-+` and the terminal will catch `Ctrl-+` and interpret that as a command to change the font size.

Just make sure you're releasing the `Ctrl` key before you execute the second keystroke of the command: `Ctrl-W`, then release `Ctrl`, then press `+` or `-`.